# What is the meaning of the numbers in Princess Bubblegum's electrocardiogram?

Tags: adventure-time

At the beginning of the [Mortal Recoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Folly_/_Mortal_Recoil) episode of *Adventure Time*, we can see this electrocardiogram of Princess Bubblegum.

---

[image]

---

The number [Pi (π)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) is pretty obvious here. But what about the other numbers? Googling around I've found the following:

- 92653 is one Zip code of [Laguna Hills, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguna_Hills,_California).
- 58979 is the [ISBN of a book](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL8843927M/Beachcomber's_Guide_to_Gulf_Coast_Marine_Life) mentioned in the [Callinectes sapidus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callinectes_sapidus) crab Wikiipedia page.

None of those two numbers make sense... do they? Is there an explanation for those numbers?

Comment: At first I was like "What other numbers? I only see π and 00."

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[It's just a continuation of Pi](http://www.piday.org/million/). 92653-58979 are the next digits. **3.14159265358979...**

Also [explained on Wikia](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Mortal_Recoil):

> In the emergency room at the start of the episode, the heart monitor screen is displaying the first 15 digits of pi.

Comment: Oh my God... is so obvious once you see it.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster you must be having the worst feeling right about now :P

Comment: @Restioson you can tell! #n_n#